# programmatically add column key id linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Under `ASP net core 3.1.` I have an `Entity Framework` `query` that constructs a `List<Type>` like this:

```
   var opts = _context.Opt_I30                        
             .Where(x => x.UnderlyingSymbol == "SPX" && x.QuoteDatetime < dt)
             .Select(x => new { x.UnderlyingSymbol, x.QuoteDatetime, x.Expiration, x.Strike, 
                                x.OptionType, x.Bid, x.Ask, x.UnderlyingBid, x.UnderlyingAsk, x.IV })
             .OrderBy(x => x.QuoteDatetime)
             .ThenBy(x => x.Expiration)
             .ThenBy(x => x.OptionType)
             .ThenBy(x => x.Strike)
             .ToList()
             ;
```

In the `Select`, how do I add a unique ID to the rows? This doesn't seem to work:

```
long id = 0;
new { id++, x.UnderlyingSymbol, x.QuoteDatetime, x.Expiration, x.Strike, 
                                    x.OptionType, x.Bid, x.Ask, x.UnderlyingBid, x.UnderlyingAsk, x.IV })
```

**EDIT 1**

If I try to modify the `select` to this:

```
Select((x, index) => new { index, x.UnderlyingSymbol, x.QuoteDatetime, x.Expiration, x.Strike, 
                                            x.OptionType, x.Bid, x.Ask, x.UnderlyingBid, x.UnderlyingAsk, x.IV })
```

I get an exception:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NotSupportedException: Could not parse expression 'value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[OptionsAPI.Entities.Option]).Where(x => ((x.UnderlyingSymbol == "SPX") AndAlso (x.QuoteDatetime < __dt_0))).Select((x, index) => new <>f__AnonymousType0`11(index = index, UnderlyingSymbol = x.UnderlyingSymbol, QuoteDatetime = x.QuoteDatetime, Expiration = x.Expiration, Strike = x.Strike, OptionType = x.OptionType, Bid = x.Bid, Ask = x.Ask, UnderlyingBid = x.UnderlyingBid, UnderlyingAsk = x.UnderlyingAsk, IV = x.IV))': This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Select' is currently not supported.
Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.MethodCallExpressionParser.GetNodeType(MethodCallExpression expressionToParse)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
NotSupportedException: Could not parse expression 'value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[OptionsAPI.Entities.Option]).Where(x => ((x.UnderlyingSymbol == "SPX") AndAlso (x.QuoteDatetime < __dt_0))).Select((x, index) => new <>f__AnonymousType0`11(index = index, UnderlyingSymbol = x.UnderlyingSymbol, QuoteDatetime = x.QuoteDatetime, Expiration = x.Expiration, Strike = x.Strike, OptionType = x.OptionType, Bid = x.Bid, Ask = x.Ask, UnderlyingBid = x.UnderlyingBid, UnderlyingAsk = x.UnderlyingAsk, IV = x.IV))': This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Select' is currently not supported.
```

....

Comment: So you just want another property which increments by 1?

Comment: Right per each row retrieved from the database.

Comment: Does it have to be an integer or can it be anything?

Comment: An uint. Just as if I had made a database generated unique ID for each row entry.

Comment: @Pavel's answer is right on the dot. Just wondering, you are selecting a lot of fields of `x` as well as the index. Why not just select `x` and the index?

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable.Select` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) has an overload, which represents an integer index in source collection, you can try to use it as an index and id for row

```cs
.Select((x, i) => new { x.UnderlyingSymbol, x.QuoteDatetime, x.Expiration, x.Strike, 
                                x.OptionType, x.Bid, x.Ask, x.UnderlyingBid, x.UnderlyingAsk, i })
```

Since you are using EF Core, your `Linq` methods return `IQueryable` instead of `IEnumerable`. In this case make sense to use `Select` overload after you evaluate your results `ToList()`. Then you'll be able to add the required index

Comment: See EDIT 1 in original post.

Comment: @Ivan you might need to add the index after the query was constructed and executed.

Comment: @Ivan You didn't mentioned that you are using EF core. `IQueryable` doesn't support that. You can convert the query to list or ienumerable to perform the select operation

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski the OP really should do that after the `.ToList` which is already there, otherwise the sorting and the where statement won't be executed from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Using the comments suggestions, the answer is to insert the ID to the list like this:

```
var opts = _context.Opt_I30                        
                         .Where(x => x.UnderlyingSymbol == "SPX" && x.QuoteDatetime < dt)
                         .Select(x => new Option{ UnderlyingSymbol = x.UnderlyingSymbol, 
                                                  QuoteDatetime = x.QuoteDatetime, 
                                                  Expiration = x.Expiration, 
                                                  Strike = x.Strike, 
                                                  OptionType = x.OptionType, 
                                                  Bid = x.Bid, 
                                                  Ask = x.Ask, 
                                                  UnderlyingBid = x.UnderlyingBid, 
                                                  UnderlyingAsk = x.UnderlyingAsk, 
                                                  IV = x.IV })
                         .OrderBy(x => x.QuoteDatetime)
                         .ThenBy(x => x.Expiration)
                         .ThenBy(x => x.OptionType)
                         .ThenBy(x => x.Strike)
                         .ToList()
                         ;

               var newopts = opts.Select((x, i) => new { i, x.UnderlyingSymbol, x.QuoteDatetime, x.Expiration, x.Strike, 
                                                  x.OptionType, x.Bid, x.Ask, x.UnderlyingBid, x.UnderlyingAsk });

               return Ok(newopts);
```